# My App crashing when i open new tab in tabbar iOS 6.0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, crash, uitabbarcontroller

I am creating a news app in that I have mainly 2 UIViewcontrollers:

1. Breaking news
2. Home Page

Breaking news show the latest news available with tile images and some description.
And in Home Page I can select which kind of news I wanted like sports, politics etc. So every time it will display that type of news inside Home Page.

**My problem is**

When I open app, then I can see breaking news and I clicked on one news item so it will open in new `UIViewController` with all images and description related to that news.

If I clicked next tabbar button from that Description page it will open Home `UIViewController` and crashing. Sometimes I can see Home `UIViewController` and when I open a news then it's crashing.

If I clicked back button then I will reach breaking news page and then it's not crashing.

BUT THIS PROBLEM APPEARING ONLY IN iOS 6.0+ Version. I tried to run the same app in iOS 5.1 Device it's Working fine.

**crash logs**

```
 -[DescriptionPageViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1f59a370`
```

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE** 
 JUST NOW I TRIED TO RUN THE SAME USE CASE with breakpoint  IN ipad 6.1 simulator again   but its working fine there and crashing without breakpoint device***  why ????

Appdelegate codes

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"everLaunched"]==YES) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"everLaunched"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"firstLaunch"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];



            [self loadingControllers];
                    }


    return YES;

}
-(void)loadingControllers{


    BreakingNewsViewController *breaking = [[BreakingNewsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BreakingNewsViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *home = [[homepage alloc] initWithNibName:@"homepage" bundle:nil];



    UINavigationController*viewController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:breaking];
    UINavigationController *viewController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:home];


    viewController1.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    viewController2.navigationBarHidden = YES;


    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Tabbar_bg.png"];
    // self.tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1,
                                             viewController2
                                            ,nil];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self.tabBarController setDelegate:self];




}
```

Comment: Crashing...crashing...crashing.. Add crash log to the question!!

Comment: @Anil before you posting this am already added logs ok

Comment: When i start commenting it was not there..:) Are you using ARC?

Comment: @Anil  yes.its ARC .  the above crash logs only getting in ios 6.0 simulator   . In device am not getting any logs and  i can saw only  "EXC BAD ACCESS code=1 Address=0x8"

Comment: Using UINavigationController ..?

Comment: @KumarKl yes am using UINavigation controller

Comment: Please check updates in my question

Comment: Please stop using so much uppercase (yelling) and so much bold text. It makes your question very annoying to read.

Comment: I just suggest You to Clean Your Project and build it . This might be the issue with ARC and your TabBarController . do some changes in appDelegate for Tabbar...

Comment: @KumarKl last 24hrs am cleaning this thing its not working..i dont know why its working in iOS 5.1 and crashing in   iOS 6.0

Comment: @shwethap . R U using StoryBoard?

Comment: @KumarKl no ..its Xib's

Comment: Where is DescriptionPageViewController object allocated and initialized?

Comment: @Puneet its inside Breaking news.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are allocating/initializing `DescriptionPageViewController` inside `BreakingNewsViewController`.

Please, create property for `DescriptionPageViewController` object with strong attributes.

```
 // In BreakingNewsViewController.h

@property (strong, nonatomic) DescriptionPageViewController *descriptionPageViewController;

 // In BreakingNewsViewController.m

self.descriptionPageViewController = [[DescriptionPageViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DescriptionPageViewController "];
```

Comment: @AM running now with ur modification

Comment: puneet with your changes app working in simulator ..now am trying in device let me know u the staus

Comment: Thanks alot puneet its working ...may i knw why its crashing before the reason?

Comment: See what happens is, that in ARC the object gets deallocated once it is used, if you have not made it strong. Strong is equivalent to retain in ARC.

Comment: @ok .now i have to fix another crash also .catch u later